Запись у домена, для чего применяется
Не помню, давно, видимо провайдер добавил.
В днс панели, в записи к домену, присутствует запись
TTL: 3600
Тип: TXT (текстовая запись) 
Значение: v=spf1 ip4:*.*.*.* a mx ~all

Для чего предназначена данная запись?

Это перечень серверов, которые имеют право отправлять почту для адресов вашего домена. Крупные почтовые ящика, гугл и ко, проверяют эту запись, и если почта пришла с иного IP, отбрасывают письмо. https://support.google.com/a/answer/10683907?hl=en

Логичнее было бы перенести ваш комментарий в ответ на вопрос, так как он содержит именно ответ.
